# Flash classic textfield with embedded font stop working when I use antialias

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, textfield

I'm using Flash CS5.5, working with some graphics and using some classic textfields. But, one day I opened the fla and all the embedded textfields were blank. I changed it to other fonts and worked perfectly, but not the font I was using (Myriad Pro). It only works if I choose "Use device fonts".
So, does it has to do with some cache or something?
I've erased all the fonts, rebooted my computer, and again the same problem.

It's not a scripting problem, may be a bug in flash?

UPDATE:
In fact none of the OpenType CFF are working in my Flash. How can I restore these fonts?

UPDATE 2:
Does it has to do with the Windows XP updates of 13/12/12? Someone has another SO with the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Some fonts work and some don't. It just started happening yesterday. If I change the text fields to TLF, they show up, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Actually I had to convert all the OpenType CFF to TTF, now I can continue working, but that's not a solution.

Comment: Great minds think alike. That's exactly what I did. I think that's going to be the best solution.  We're using Windows 7 and we suspect there was a Windows update yesterday that caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem with CS5 in Win7. And I also got a Windows update last night.

This info may be relevant: http://graphics-unleashed.unleash.com/2012/12/windows-update-kb2753842-will-make-some.html?showComment=1355447264092

....

Okay, I've tried it and can confirm that uninstalling KB2753842 fixes the problem for me.